# Common usage of "be tried for one's life"

Tags: phrase-usage, legalese, contemporary-english

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XXII, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_22); Passage 348:

> The public house and tea garden called the Currency Lass represented a moderate fortune gained by its proprietor, Captain Bostock, during a long, active, and occasionally historic career among the islands. Anywhere from Tonga to the Admiralty Isles, he knew the ropes and could lie in the native dialect. He had seen the end of sandal wood, the end of oil, and the beginning of copra; and he was himself a commercial pioneer, the first that ever carried human teeth into the Gilberts. **He was tried for his life in Fiji** in Sir Arthur Gordon's time; and if ever he prayed at all, the name of Sir Arthur was certainly not forgotten. He was speared in seven places in New Ireland—the same time his mate was killed—the famous “outrage on the brig Jolly Roger;” but the treacherous savages made little by their wickedness, and Bostock, in spite of their teeth, got seventy-five head of volunteer labour on board, of whom not more than a dozen died of injuries.

Is the phrase "be tried for one's life" common usage or is it obsolete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly 'in common usage' in the UK, since we no longer have the death penalty, but it would be perfectly well understood in a historical context.

Comment: I think that is all there is to be said about the matter.  Even in the US, where any of the States retain capital punishment, capital punishment is not as it was two centuries ago, where, once found guilty, the person was taken out either immediately or very soon after conviction and hanged.  Now most of the time the death sentence is followed by years, even decades, of appeals before whatever kind of execution is carried out.  'Trial for ones life' has an imminence about it that belies the soul-destroying length of the wait.  But the phrase will indeed do fine.

Comment: I find the clause **got seventy-five head of volunteer labour on board** more strange unless, as I suspect, this was Stevenson being ironic and referring to slavery.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the fact that he "carried human teeth into the Gilberts"  and the fact that the volunteers came on board "despite their teeth".